# Can I embed an object array inside a schema in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How would I insert an object array into a schema?My current code:

```
const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: String,
  content: String
})

const Comment = mongoose.model("Comment", postSchema);

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  content: String,
  comments: [Comment]
});
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Invalid schema configuration: `model` is not a valid type within the array `comments`.
```

How should I properly insert a list of objects? I am trying to make a list of comments under each post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: String,
  content: String
})
    
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  content: String,
  comments: [commentSchema]
});
```

Here is a link for mongoose [Subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)